# Regex for empty string or white space

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to detect if a user enter whitespace in a textbox:

```
 var regex = "^\s+$" ; 
 if($("#siren").val().match(regex)) {
     echo($("#siren").val());
     error+=1;
    $("#siren").addClass("error");
    $(".div-error").append("- Champ Siren/Siret ne doit pas etre vide<br/>");
 }
```

`if($("#siren").val().match(regex))` is supposed to match whitespace string, however, it doesn' t seems to work, what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for your helps

Comment: When you say "doesn't seems to work", could you be more specific? Are there any example inputs that fail that you could share?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The `\` (backslash) in the `.match` call is not properly escaped.  It would be easier to use a regex literal though.  Either will work:

```
var regex = "^\\s+$";
var regex = /^\s+$/;
```

Also note that `+` will require at least one space.  You may want to use `*`.

Comment: I use var regex = "^\\s+$"; it works like a charm, thank you very much all of you

Answer (score 38):

If you are looking for empty string in addition to whitespace you meed to use * rather than +

```
var regex = /^\s*$/ ;
                ^
```

Answer (score 24):

If you're using jQuery, you have `.trim()`.

```
if ($("#siren").val().trim() == "") {
  // it's empty
}
```

Comment: If you only need to support JavaScript 1.8 browsers, there is [String.trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Comment: @ExplosionPills I'm sure that jQuery does this internally, and OP already uses jQuery.

Comment: @Overcode where do you see simplicity? trim() uses a regex too, more complicated than /^\s*$/

Comment: IMHO, this shows the intent of the code more clear than a regex. Saying `foo.trim() == ''` is saying "Is this string, ignoring space, empty?". Saying `foo.match(/^\s*$/)` is asking "Does the string foo match the state machine defined by the regex?". Yes, the regex is simple, but it's still less clear. You're also not guaranteed for `trim` to be defined via a regex, a lot of JS engines have it built-in.

Comment: @yan point taken about native trim. As for the "state machine" part, you're overdoing it :-)

Comment: Though `var regex = new RegExp(REGEX.blank); return regex.test(val);` does the same, but I really like the way you leverage javascript API without using regex. +1 for simplicity

Comment: This answer is not using jQuery's trim! It is using native string trim, because `val()` returns a string (usually, which brings me to my next point.)

`$("#siren").val()` will return `undefined` if no elements are matched for the selector `#siren`, and then of course an error will be thrown when you try to call the method `trim` on `undefined`.

To use jQuery's `trim` method, you would write: `$.trim($("#siren").val());`

Answer (score 5):

If one only cares about whitespace at the beginning and end of the string (but not in the middle), then another option is to use String.trim():

```js
"    your string contents  ".trim();

// => "your string contents"
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/DqGB8/1/

This is my solution

```
var error=0;
var test = [" ", "   "];
 if(test[0].match(/^\s*$/g)) {
     $("#output").html("MATCH!");
     error+=1;
 } else {
     $("#output").html("no_match");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem, was looking for white spaces in a string, solution:

- To search for 1 space:

  ```
  var regex = /^.+\s.+$/ ;
  ```

  example: "user last_name"
- To search for multiple spaces:

  ```
  var regex = /^.+\s.+$/g ;
  ```

  example: "user last name"