# Add regex to an input field without using Form

Tags: angular

I am trying to add regex to an input field in my angular app. The input field belongs to an HTML set which does not make use of a Form. The regex is to check that the input field is not empty. Is this possible to do? I would like to add it in my validateName function if possible.

Here is my code

> HTML

```
<div>
  <div class="ui-g">
    <div class="tab-container">
      <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-12">
        <strong style="padding-left:12px;">Template Name</strong>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-12 ">
        <div class="input-container">
          <label for="jobTitle">Template name*</label>
          <input id="jobTitle" type="text" [disabled]="mode == 'view'" [(ngModel)]="templateName" size="100" (keyup)="validateName()">
        </div>
        <p class="error" *ngIf="!isValid">
          * An offer template with this name already exists.
        </p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> TS

```
validateName() {
    const regexBlankInput = "^\\s+$";
    if(this.templateName != '' ) {
      const found = this.usersService.allTemplates.some(x => x.name.toLowerCase() == this.templateName.toLowerCase());
      if ((found) || (this.templateName == regexBlankInput)) { 
      this.isValid = false;
      } else{
        this.isValid = true;
      }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use forms?

Comment: An example using forms can be found here: https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-4-pattern-validation-example

Comment: I guess I'll try forms. I was just supposed to modify the code from another developer.

Comment: is there something not working with your code?

Comment: @AJT82 yes, I am not appending regex correctly and was hoping it was possible to do without using Forms

Comment: Just go with forms, they're designed for exact this use case. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go for Forms as how many validation method will you write for different field or same fields which needs different type of validations. ex: templatename if needs to check blank, trailing space,max length, special char etc.

But if you dont want to change existing architecture,

```
 var regex = /^\s+$/;   //got from here 
                        //https://stackoverflow.com/a/19121430/7562674
 var patt = new RegExp(regex);

 if(this.templateName != '' ) {
  var res = patt.test(this.templateName);   //true when it templateName is blank
  const found = this.usersService.allTemplates.some(x => x.name.toLowerCase() == 
  this.templateName.toLowerCase());
  if ((found) || res ) { 
  this.isValid = false;
  } else{
    this.isValid = true;
  }
}
```

=> https://angular.io/guide/form-validation  == Forms validation in angular.