# Regex Expression to restrict the space character in a password field using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have a need to put a RegEx expression over a property in a model on a MVC website that I'm working on.

The different pieces of the expression make sense to me individually, but I can't figure out how to form them together.

I have to restrict password field to letters, capital letters, numbers, and the symbols, but not space character

I then need to ensure that the following criteria is met by the user

Input must contain 1 capital letter
Input must contain 1 number
Input must contain one special character.
Input must not contain the Space character

I've tried below regex, but space character validation is not working

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?=.*\d)(?!.*\s)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}$
```

This is working as expected

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you get more luck with this
[Regex for empty string or white space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121375/regex-for-empty-string-or-white-space)
I guess it was answered in a lot of ways over there

Comment: Need to add the space validation to this ^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,}$ regex

Comment: \s'  this is part is showing an error as it has a single quote